# Integrating Select2 with Magento 2

Tags: requirejs, magento2, jquery-select2

I'm trying to integrate Select2 with Magento2. So far I have integrated the plugin successfully but there are errors showing on the console.
[image]

What I've done:

1. Downloaded the select2.min.js and put it in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<themename>/web/js/select2.min.js`
2. Included the script in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<themename>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`
3. Added this to the phtml file in script tags:

   `require(['jquery'],function(jquery){ 
         jquery(document).load(function() { 
               jquery("#sorter2").select2(); 
         }); 
    });`

I know I should it include it via requireJS but I can't seem to make it work.

### Thanks!

Comment: Where is your require.js config? After you have added "select2" to the config, you can set it as a dependency: 
`require(['jquery','select2'],function(jquery){ `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't add it in the header on every page as it's dependencies won't necessarily load.  You need to add it to your themes requirejs-config here;

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/requirejs-config.js
```

In the file put this;

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'select2': 'js/select2.min',
    },
};
```

Now in any phtml file you can call it like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','select2'],function($){
        // do stuff with select
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but I think there is one issue. Why do u put "Select2" into the shim config part? This is only for non AMD modules! Select2 is AMD ready and it already defines jQuery as an dependency.

Comment: ah fair enough, we've had to declare the jquery dependency on other jquery plugins.

Comment: Cool. Will try this out in a bit and update you guys when it works. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! I also did not put the shim config part based on Legends comment. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'select2': 'SATA_SparePartsFinder/js/vendor/select2.full'
    }
};
```

in your `.phtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'select2'], function($) {
        $('#model-select').select2({language: {
                noResults: function () {
                    return '<?= __('No results found') ?>';
                }
            }});
    });
</script>
```